# java.lang.NullPointerException массив int в Java

Tags: java

Думаю тут элементарная проблема и код не нужен. Я создаю массив интов в конструкторе класса, который является полем этого класса. `private int[] prices;`  В конструкторе объявляю через: 
`this.prices = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};`. Потом через цикл вывожу эти элементы в консоль - выводятся.
Есть элементарный геттер этого массива. Потом у объекта этого класса через геттер я беру этот массив и запрашиваю его длину `tour.getPrices().length;`, но вдруг вылетает nullpointerException. Я думал такие ошибки не будут вылетать при использовании примитивных типов.
Наверняка я что-то недогоняю в инициализации, но навряд ли. Может вы подскажете?

UPDATE: 
Предоставляю код.
Класс, где хранятся массивы:

```
public class Tour {
private String depPoint, arrPoint;
private float price = 0;
private Image[] images;
private int[] prices;
private int rating = 2;
private Image img0, img1, img2, img3, img4, img5;
private boolean isHotel = false;
private int id;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getDepPoint() {
    return depPoint;
}

public void setDepPoint(String depPoint) {
    this.depPoint = depPoint;
}

public String getArrPoint() {
    return arrPoint;
}

public void setArrPoint(String arrPoint) {
    this.arrPoint = arrPoint;
}

public float getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(float price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public Image[] getImages() {
    return images;
}

public void setImages(String[] names)  {
   /* images = new Image[names.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        Image img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("src/com/company/assets/" + names[i]));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        images[i] = img;
    }*/
}

public int[] getPrices() {
    return prices;
}

public void setPrices(int[] prices) {
    this.prices = prices;
}

public int getRating() {
    return rating;
}

public void setRating(int rate){
    this.rating = rate;
}

public void setHotel(){
    if(!isHotel){
        price += 20000;
        isHotel = true;
    }

}

public void disposeHotel() {
    if(isHotel) {
        price -= 20000;
        isHotel = false;
    }
}

public boolean isHotel() {return isHotel;}

Tour(String depPoint, String arrPoint, Image[] images, int[] prices, int price, int rating, int id){
    this.depPoint = depPoint;
    this.arrPoint = arrPoint;
    try {
        img0 = ImageIO.read(new File("src/com/company/assets/rating0.png"));
        img1 = ImageIO.read(new File("src/com/company/assets/rating1.png"));
        img2 = ImageIO.read(new File("src/com/company/assets/rating2.png"));
        img3 = ImageIO.read(new File("src/com/company/assets/rating3.png"));
        img4 = ImageIO.read(new File("src/com/company/assets/rating4.png"));
        img5 = ImageIO.read(new File("src/com/company/assets/rating5.png"));
        this.images = new Image[]{img0, img1, img2, img3, img4, img5};
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.prices = new int[]{50000,30000,100000,40000};
    this.price = price;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Город отправления:" + depPoint + "\tГород прибытия: " + arrPoint + "\nСтоимость: " + price + "\n\n";
}
```

}

Класс, где я работаю с объектом, в полях которого массивы:

```
public class TourFrame extends JFrame {
private JLabel picture, departureLabel, arrivalLabel, priceLabel, depDateLabel, arrDateLabel, ratingLabel, reviewsLabel;
private JDateChooser depDateChooser, arrDateChooser;
private JButton addToCartButton, leftButton, rightButton, graphicButton;
private JCheckBox hotelCheckBox;
private String depPoint, arrPoint;
private float price = 0;
private Image[] images;
private JPanel picturePanel, arrDateChooserPanel, depDateChooserPanel, ratingPanel, ratingPicturePanel, mainPicturePanel, depArrLabelsPanel, depArrChoosersPanel, hotelPriceButtonPanel, ratingGraphicPanel, reviewPanel;
private JScrollPane reviewsScrollPane;
private JTextArea reviewsTextArea;
private Tour tour;
private TourPanel parent;
private PicturePanel[] picturePanels;


TourFrame(Tour _tour, TourPanel _parent) {
    tour = _tour;
    parent = _parent;
    if (parent.getHotelCheckBox().isSelected()) tour.setHotel();
    init();
    leftButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CardLayout layout = (CardLayout) picturePanel.getLayout();
            layout.previous(picturePanel);
        }
    });
    rightButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CardLayout layout = (CardLayout) picturePanel.getLayout();
            layout.next(picturePanel);
        }
    });
    addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {
        @Override
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) { }
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            parent.closeFrame();
        }
        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) { }
        @Override
        public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) { }
        @Override
        public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) { }
        @Override
        public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) { }
        @Override
        public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) { }
    });
    setVisible(true);
}

public void init() {

    setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
    setTitle("Относительно подробная информация");
    picturePanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
    //PicturePanel[] picturePanels;
    System.out.println(tour.getImages().length); // ТУТ ВСЕ РАБОТАЕТ ИДЕАЛЬНО.
    if (tour.getImages() != null) {
        picturePanels = new PicturePanel[tour.getImages().length];
        for (int i = 0; i < tour.getImages().length; i++) {
            picturePanels[i] = new PicturePanel(tour.getImages()[i], picturePanel);
            picturePanel.add("pic0" + (i + 1) + " ", picturePanels[i]);
        }
    }
    leftButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    rightButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    departureLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    arrivalLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    depDateLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    arrDateLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    depDateChooserPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    arrDateChooserPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    if (parent.getHotelCheckBox().isSelected()) hotelCheckBox = new javax.swing.JCheckBox("", true);
    else hotelCheckBox = new javax.swing.JCheckBox("", false);
    hotelCheckBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if(hotelCheckBox.isSelected()) tour.setHotel();
            else tour.disposeHotel();
            priceLabel.setText("Итоговая стоимость: " + tour.getPrice());
        }
    });
    priceLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    addToCartButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    ratingPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    ratingLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    ratingPicturePanel = new RatingPicturePanel(tour.getRating());
    reviewsLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    reviewsTextArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    reviewsScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane(reviewsTextArea);
    graphicButton = new JButton();
    arrDateChooser = new JDateChooser();
    depDateChooser = new JDateChooser();

    graphicButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(tour.getPrices() == null) System.out.println("null");
            System.out.println(tour.getPrices().length); // ТУТ УЖЕ НЕ РАБОТАЕТ.
            new GraphicDialog(TourFrame.this, tour);

        }
    });

    addToCartButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           parent.checkValid(parent);
        }
    });

    reviewsTextArea.setEditable(false);
    Font font = reviewsTextArea.getFont();
    reviewsTextArea.setFont(font.deriveFont(font.getSize() + 3.5f));
    updateReview();
    reviewsTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
    setSize(1053, 709);
    setResizable(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    leftButton.setText("<-");
    rightButton.setText("->");
    departureLabel.setText("Город отправления: " + tour.getDepPoint());
    arrivalLabel.setText("Город прибытия: " + tour.getArrPoint());
    depDateLabel.setText("Дата отправления");
    arrDateLabel.setText("Дата прибытия");
    hotelCheckBox.setText("Отель");
    priceLabel.setText("Итоговая стоимость: " + tour.getPrice());
    addToCartButton.setText("Добавить в корзину");
    ratingLabel.setText("Рейтинг");
    reviewsLabel.setText("Отзывы");
    reviewsTextArea.setColumns(20);
    reviewsTextArea.setRows(5);
    reviewsScrollPane.setViewportView(reviewsTextArea);
    graphicButton.setText("График изменения цены");

    mainPicturePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    mainPicturePanel.add(leftButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
    mainPicturePanel.add(picturePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainPicturePanel.add(rightButton, BorderLayout.EAST);

    depArrLabelsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
    depArrLabelsPanel.add(departureLabel);
    depArrLabelsPanel.add(arrivalLabel);
    departureLabel.setAlignmentY(JComponent.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    arrivalLabel.setAlignmentY(JComponent.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    depArrChoosersPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    depDateChooserPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(depDateChooserPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    arrDateChooserPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(arrDateChooserPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    depDateChooserPanel.add(depDateLabel);
    depDateChooserPanel.add(depDateChooser);
    arrDateChooserPanel.add(arrDateLabel);
    arrDateChooserPanel.add(arrDateChooser);
    depArrChoosersPanel.add(depDateChooserPanel);
    depArrChoosersPanel.add(arrDateChooserPanel);

    hotelPriceButtonPanel = new JPanel();
    hotelPriceButtonPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(hotelPriceButtonPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    hotelPriceButtonPanel.add(hotelCheckBox);
    hotelPriceButtonPanel.add(priceLabel);
    hotelPriceButtonPanel.add(addToCartButton);
    hotelCheckBox.setAlignmentX(JComponent.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    priceLabel.setAlignmentX(JComponent.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    addToCartButton.setAlignmentX(JComponent.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    ratingGraphicPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    ratingPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(ratingPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    ratingPanel.add(ratingLabel);
    ratingPanel.add(ratingPicturePanel);
    ratingGraphicPanel.add(ratingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    ratingGraphicPanel.add(graphicButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    reviewPanel = new JPanel();
    reviewPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel tempPanel = new JPanel();
    tempPanel.add(reviewsLabel);
    JButton reviewButton = new JButton("Добавить отзыв");
    tempPanel.add(reviewButton);
    reviewPanel.add(tempPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    reviewPanel.add(reviewsScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    reviewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new ReviewDialog(TourFrame.this, tour);
        }
    });

    add(mainPicturePanel);
    add(depArrLabelsPanel);
    add(depArrChoosersPanel);
    add(hotelPriceButtonPanel);
    add(ratingGraphicPanel);
    add(reviewPanel);


}
public void updateReview(){
    String msg = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < Singleton.getCollection().getReviews().size(); i++) {
        if (tour == Singleton.getCollection().getReview(i).getTour()) msg += Singleton.getCollection().getReview(i);
    }
    reviewsTextArea.setText(msg);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tour = new Tour();
tour.getPrices().length;
```

---

Вы возвращаете `null` из `getPrices`.

Comment: tour иниуиализирован. Еще один забавный факт,кстати. Подобным образом так же в конструкторе создан еще массив private Image[] .... Но все, что я проделываю с массивом интов здесь работает. Я так же его инициализирую, так же через геттер получаю, так же tour.getImages().length, вот только с этим массивом все работает, а с интами нет.

Comment: @НикитаСкворцов Нет, не инициализирован.

Comment: Этот tour у меня в синглтоне, он всегда инициализован.

Comment: Так почему с одним массивом работает, а с другим нет? Я с ними делаю абчолютно одинкаовые действия

Comment: @НикитаСкворцов Я должен Вам поверить на слово? Ну ждите, кто-то другой угадает, что у Вас не так.

Comment: @НикитаСкворцов Значит - не одинаковые. Но без кода - разговор беспредметный.

Comment: Igor, я обновил свой вопрос.

Comment: @НикитаСкворцов Где создается объект типа `Tour`?

Comment: При выгрузки из базы данных, я же там отметил комментариями, где код работает и где уже не работает, хотя не логично. ТУТ РАБОТАЕТ; ТУТ УЖЕ НЕ РАБОТАЕТ. Второе приложение.

Comment: @НикитаСкворцов Вы где-то вызываете `setPrices` с параметром, кoторый `null`.

Comment: Неа, не вызываю. Я эти методы создал для моего соавтора. К тому же, если для вас это доказательство, в Intellij методы setImages и setPrices отмечены серым цветом, что говорит об их безучастии)

Comment: @НикитаСкворцов `if(tour.getPrices() == null) System.out.println("null");` - выводит `null`?

Comment: Все ясно, я додик в другом модуле вызывал сеттер с пустым параметром, не помню зачем. Спасибо! Отметил ваш ответ как решение.

Comment: @НикитаСкворцов Пожалуйста. Успехов!